# How to upload a Video in iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone

I want to upload a video to webserver. I can upload the video but the problem  is how should i pick a video. Means I know there is a default UIImagePickerController that i can use to pick image, is there any thing similar to pick movies in iPhone?

Hope you are getting my problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this [SO entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1381514/uiimagepickercontroller-for-movie-item). It has a similar discussion.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ddd" ofType:@"avi"];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

Answer (score 0):

Assets library is another option that you can fetch all photos and videos programaticaly but in that you case you have to make your own pickerviewcontroller .

Answer (score 0):

Use AVFoundation to capture video and upload it using MKNetworkKit.