# Analyse pre-recorded video with OpenCV in iOS

Tags: ios, opencv

I am writing an app that uses OpenCV to process live video from an iPhone or iPad's onboard camera - which is working fine. Does anybody know whether it is possible to load a saved video from the Photo Album and process this?

Many thanks in advance,

Steve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.

You can use the `UIImagePickerController` to get the `NSURL` to a video file on the camera roll. Please refer to [UIImagePickerController for movie Item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1381514/uiimagepickercontroller-for-movie-item)
From the `NSURL` you can derive the file path (`-[NSURL path]` method)

You can easily read the video file using OpenCV's `VideoCapture`, the same way you probably do for the webcam :  `bool VideoCapture::open(const string& filename)`

That should do it!

Comment: Hi Thank you for your reply. In the iOS version of OpenCV the video camera has it's own object (CvVideoCamera) which has a delegate method (processImage) in which the processing for each frame is done. I can't find an equivalent object or method for a stored video file. I'll look into whether I can use VideoCapture and hook it up to my ImageView control.

Comment: Yes, you're right. `CvVideoCamera` is not great at all... I would recommend creating an the `AVCaptureSession` yourself and convert the `CVPixelBuffers` to `cv::Mat` yourself. Gives you much better control.